# yum remove silently failing

Tags: centos, yum

Using yum remove on some packages just silently fails.  For example:

```
root# yum -y remove rdma
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rdma.noarch 0:7.3_4.7_rc2-5.el7 will be erased
Removing rdma.noarch 0:7.3_4.7_rc2-5.el7 - e due to obsoletes from installed rdma-core-15-7.el7_5.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * extras: space
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rdma.noarch 0:7.3_4.7_rc2-5.el7 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
root# echo $?
0
root# rpm -q rdma
rdma-7.3_4.7_rc2-5.el7.noarch
```

I have run 'rm -r /var/cache/yum/*' and rebuilt rpm dbs but it does not fix the situation.  Using 'rpm -e' on the package works fine.

This is yum 3.4.3 on a CentOS7 box.

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Smells like a yum bug to me.

Comment: Try again with `yum -v -y remove rdma` and post the output.

Comment: This issue on this box is due to a reboot when yum was installing both rdma and rdma-core which obsoleted it were installed.  Still, yum should see this and not fail the way it does.   rpm -e still worked